# How do I make tkinter mainloop wait for a matplotlib click event

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, click, wait

I am buildin a GUI with an embedded plot using Tkinter and matplotlib. I have embedded a figure in my window and am now looking to use matplotlib's event handler to get two sets of x,y coordinates from the graph and then use these coordinates to create a straight line which is subtracted from the data in the graph. A simplified version of the code looks like this:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import tkinter as tk

#ideally this uses matplotlib's event handler and also waits for a click before registering the cooridnates
def choose_points():
    points = []
    window.bind("<Button-1>", on_click)
    points.append(graph_xy)
    window.bind("<Button-1>", on_click)
    points.append(graph_xy)
    return points

def on_click(event):
    window.unbind("<Button-1")
    window.config(cursor="arrow")
    graph_xy[0]=event.x
    graph_xy[1]=event.y

def line(x1=0,y1=0,x2=1,y2=1000):
    m=(y2-y1)/(x2-x1)
    c=y2-m*x2
    line_data=[]
    for val in range(0,20):
        line_data.append(val*m + c)
    return line_data

def build_line():
    points = []
    points = choose_points()
    #store line in line_list
    line_list=line(points[0],points[1],points[2],points[3])

#lists needed
line_list=[]
graph_xy=[0,0]

#GUI
window=tk.Tk()
window.title("IPES Graphing Tool")
window.geometry('1150x840')

#Make a frame for the graph
plot_frame = tk.Frame(window)
plot_frame.pack(side = tk.TOP,padx=5,pady=5)

#Button for making the straight line
line_btn = ttk.Button(plot_frame,text="Build line", command = build_line)
line_btn.grid(row=4, column=2,sticky='w')

#make empty figure
fig1=plt.figure(figsize=(9,7))
ax= fig1.add_axes([0.1,0.1,0.65,0.75])

#embed matplotlib figure
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig1, plot_frame)
mpl_canvas=canvas.get_tk_widget()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(padx=20,side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=False)
toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, plot_frame)
toolbar.update()
canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=False)

window.mainloop()
```

Obviously this example does not plot or use the line in any way, nor are the coordinates correct, since they are not converted to the coordinates of the graph. I tried replacing the `window.bind("<Button-1>",wait_click)` with `plt.connect('button_press_event',on_click)` but this does not wait for the click, and so an error occurs since the program tries to access `points` but it is empty.

I would like to use the functionality of the matplotlib event handling, so that I can use methods such as `event.xdata` and `event.inaxes` to avoid unnecessary extra work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I managed to get the functionality I wanted by tweaking @Henry Yik 's answer. The issue was resolved by simply using `canvas.mpl_disconnect(cid)`.

I basically used a button to use a function called `choose_cords()` which would take in an object called `draw` of type `DrawLine` containing the x and y coordinates to build the line. The function would then issue the command `canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', draw.get_cords)` to start listening for clicks on the graph. Once two clicks had been registered the matplotlib event handler would be disconnected from within the `draw` object. The code goes like this

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import tkinter as tk

window=tk.Tk()
window.title("IPES Graphing Tool")
window.geometry('1150x840')

plot_frame = tk.Frame(window)
plot_frame.pack(side = tk.TOP,padx=5,pady=5)

fig1=Figure(figsize=(9,7))
ax= fig1.add_axes([0.1,0.1,0.65,0.75])

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig1, window)
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(padx=20,side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=False)
toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, window)
toolbar.update()

def choose_cords(draw):
    draw.cid=canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', draw.get_cords)

class DrawLine: # a simple class to store previous cords
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = None
        self.y = None
        self.cid = None

    def get_cords(self, event):
        if self.x and self.y:
            ax.plot([self.x, event.xdata], [self.y, event.ydata])
            canvas.draw_idle()
            canvas.mpl_disconnect(self.cid)
            self.__init__()
            return
        self.x, self.y = event.xdata, event.ydata

draw = DrawLine()
draw_btn = tk.Button(window, text="Draw the Line", command=lambda:choose_cords(draw)).pack(side=tk.TOP,padx=5,pady=5)

window.mainloop()
```

I added a return after plotting the line because I want a new line every time, and not a continuation.

Thanks again Henry for your answer which spawend this one

Answer (score 1):

You should use `canvas.mpl_connect` to trigger your [events](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/users/event_handling.html), and then retrieve the `xdata` and `ydata` to plot the line. See below for sample:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import tkinter as tk

window=tk.Tk()
window.title("IPES Graphing Tool")
window.geometry('1150x840')

plot_frame = tk.Frame(window)
plot_frame.pack(side = tk.TOP,padx=5,pady=5)

fig1=Figure(figsize=(9,7))
ax= fig1.add_axes([0.1,0.1,0.65,0.75])

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig1, window)
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(padx=20,side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=False)
toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, window)
toolbar.update()

class DrawLine: # a simple class to store previous cords
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = None
        self.y = None

    def get_cords(self, event):
        if self.x and self.y:
            ax.plot([self.x, event.xdata], [self.y, event.ydata])
            canvas.draw_idle()
        self.x, self.y = event.xdata, event.ydata

draw = DrawLine()
canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', draw.get_cords)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Henry Yik, but this isn't what I was looking for. The example I put up oversimplified the problem. What I am aiming to obtain is for a user to click a button and for the program to go into a routine which takes two points from the graph (specified by click events) and then uses them to find a straight line which is then subtracted from the data in the graph. I have the subtraction routine working, but I can't get the program to wait for the user's click events before getting into this subtraction routine. Hope that makes sense. Will edit the question

Comment: The idea is the same - you wait for two cords to be picked then execute whatever function you like. You can use the about class to store the initial values and execute your function only after second selection.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I see what you mean but my question is a little different. I don't want this to execute all the time. What I would like is for this only to occur once I press a certain button. I have been trying to use your idea with this but I haven't had any luck.

Comment: I think I am getting closer. I have created a button which issues a function `choose_coords(draw)` which takes the DrawLine object and subsequently calls `canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event',draw.get_cords)` to start listening for the clicks on the graph (function stores the id of the connection). I tweaked the `get_cords` method to take the coordinates from the clicks, use them, and then do a canvas.mpl_disconnect(cid) and reinitialise the DrawLine object. Now it works!